# How do I find out if the mouse button is down?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Is there any way to find out at any time if the mouse button is down?

I have some code that runs while the mouse button is down, but if I switch away from the Flash client while the mouse button is down, then the mouse up listeners are never called, so I'd like to account for this situation by checking if the mouse button is still down.

Ideally, I'd like something like:

```
if (Mouse.isDown) {
    trace("down");
} else {
    trace("up");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding an `Event.ACTIVATE` listener. Whenever Flash receives focus, I check if the mouse button is considered to be down. Since the mouse button can't be down inside the Flash client *before* the Flash client receives focus, I can safely assume that it should be up and call the appropriate code.

Answer (score 3):

you need to check the [`MouseEvent::buttonDown`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#buttonDown) property in the [`MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_MOVE) handler to switch some `Boolean` flag

**upd**
code:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent; 
    /**
     * ...
     * @author www0z0k
     */
    [SWF (width="320", height="240", frameRate="24")]
    public class Main extends Sprite {
        private var _isDown:Boolean = false;
        public function Main():void {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            color = 0;
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMove);
        }

        private function onMove(e:MouseEvent):void {
            color = e.buttonDown ? 0xffff00 : 0x0000ff;
        }

        public function set color(value:int):void {
            graphics.clear();
            graphics.beginFill(value);
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 320, 240);
            graphics.endFill();
        }       
    }   
}
```

[result](http://www0z0k.narod.ru/bin/index.html) - i press the button, move the pointer outside firefox, relese the button, click on the other application window, then alt-tab back to firefox and move the mouse in; at this moment my swf recognizes that mouse button is released


**upd 2**
it works as supposed in firefox 3.6.10 and as described in the question in firefox 7.0.1

Comment: after the mouse pointer and focus return to the swf (and so `MOUSE_MOVE` is fired) you got wrong `buttonDown` value in that event handler?

Comment: Yes, apparently Flash still thinks the mouse button is down. If the Flash client loses focus while the mouse button is down, it never knows that in the mean time it was released, so when it receives focus again, it thinks it's still down. This doesn't happen everywhere, but I can always reproduce it in Firefox, latest 11 dev client, Windows 7.

Comment: or you are storing the previous `MouseEvent` instance and checking its `buttonDown` property? if so - it shouldn't work

Comment: sounds interesting, i'll try to reproduce ;)

Comment: I tried by adding a stage listener for `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE`, and in the function handling the event, I check for `event.buttonDown`. It's `true` after receiving focus back, even if the button is actually up.

Comment: does it happen in standalone player?

Comment: Didn't try in the standalone player.

Comment: Just tested with your link. I press the button, while keeping the button pressed I press ALT + TAB, I release the button (the Flash client is still yellow), I ALT + TAB back, I move the mouse over the Flash client, everything continues to be yellow until I finally click and it turns blue.

Comment: flash player version WIN 11,0,1,152; not debug; win7 x64; firefox 3.6.10; what about you?

Comment: just tested on Firefox 7.0.1, behaves as you described it, aso it's a firefox issue

Comment: Same thing doesn't happen on Mac with the latest Firefox though. It also happens on other browsers, but rarely, I haven't found a way to reproduce it.